# Stacking up elements in CSS doesnt work as expected

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="panel">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="container active"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my idea is to have one or more `#panel`'s in my document, wich contains more screens in it. In this case, 2 `#container`'s. And the one with the `#active` id, should be displayed at a different `z-index` level. In this case i would want it at level 2.

So i've wrote this in CSS:

```
#panel {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  background-color: green;
}

#container#active{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  background-color: yellow;

  z-index: 2;
}
```

I know `div` elements automaticly have the `display` property of `block`, but i dont see any problem in that.

I also want to be able to set one of the `display` property's to `none`.

**Problem**

At this point, nothing is happening. The second element is'nt even showing. While they are both in the document and set their `height` and `width` to `100%`.

**Question**

How would I make it so that i can stack up all these elements in one `#panel` in a efficient way?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ua6a7vhk/)**

Comment: [z-index only applies to positioned elements.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: @remyabel So am i forced to use an `absolute` position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[Basic html data types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)

So you can't use white-spaces in id. Now for your problem you can use `position:absolute` like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="activeContainer"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#panel {
    position: absolute;/*Add position absolute*/

    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#container {
    position: absolute;/*Add position absolute*/
    top:0;/*Add top 0*/

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;

    background-color: green;
}
#activeContainer {
    position: absolute;/*Add position absolute*/
    top: 0;/*Add top 0*/

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 2;

    background-color: yellow;
}
```

> **Note**: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ua6a7vhk/10/)

Comment: Thanks, but according to remyabel's comment he said that you need to use `position` to make `z-index` work. You didnt do that in this case. How does this come? (Btw, it doesnt work according to your code. It just places the element under it)

Comment: Am i forced to use `position: absolute`, is it the most common way?

Comment: Is a simple and a quick way to achieve this :)

Comment: Alright, but i dont like the `position: absolute` on the `#panel` it self, is there an alternative for that? When i remove it, it takes the element with the `position` element and makes it a `100%` width from the whole document.

Comment: You can use `position:relative` in panel. Take a look also here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning

Comment: alright, then i'll do that. I have edited your post for more code clarification. Can you accept that?